# Sqlite db on Windows - Tiny java app

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am writing tiny Java application for my school friend. I've created app which is working with sqlite database. At my PC (Netbeans, Ubuntu) everything is working fine. My friend need to launch this app at his notebook with Win7. It will be fine if I just compile same source code at his Netbeans on Win? Connection to SQLite through jdbc won't cause any problems at Windows os?

Please excuse my question, but I dont know Java very well and I'm still learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be good to go with the same source on Windows.  Just make sure the .jar files are accessible via Windows.  One thing to look out for is to make sure any paths are compatible-- in Ubuntu you may be using something like '/path/to/your/sql' where in Windows you will need something like 'C:/path/to/your/sql'.